# QSerialDevice: Compilation error "libudev.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: qt4

I checked-out the QSerialDevice from (https://gitorious.org/qserialdevice). I have to download the UDEV (http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/udev.html) but the link is broken. So, I skipped this and tried to build the library but obviously I get an error of missing libudev.h.

How can I fix this?

I am using qextserialport but am facing problems in the read, so am trying to substitute it with qserialdevice.

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't your distribution have packages for udev (and udev-devel possibly)?

Comment: I have udev under /etc, which only has a rules.d folder and udev.conf file. But i dont have libudev.h

Comment: Do you have the udev-devel packages installed?

Comment: No I don't have these packages.

Comment: Which linux distribution are you using ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For Ubuntu, install the package **libudev-dev**.

If you need other files, you can find the package that contains it with http://packages.ubuntu.com#search_contents

Comment: @newbieLinuxCpp why not select this as the answer then?