# Compilation errors in RHEL 5 libudev.h No such file or directory

Tags: c, compiler-errors, udev

All,
I'm trying to compile some code that compiles in Ubuntu after getting the udev library from "apt-get".  I am trying to get it to compile in RedHat 5 but am getting the following compile errors:

error: libudev.h: No such file or directory

The question is similar to: [QSerialDevice: Compilation error "libudev.h: No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658349/qserialdevice-compilation-error-libudev-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

However, instead of the failure happening on Ubuntu, it's happening on RedHat 5.  I tried finding the RPM files for the udev library and got one RPM file from the following link.  The RPM file was unsuccessful installing when I double clicked it stating:

"Cannot install source packages"
"No packages were given for installation"

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/i-need-libudev-or-udev-devel-for-red-hat-5-a-4175422051/

udev-147-2.42.el6.src.rpm is the name of the RPM

Any help would be appreciated.  Doing a search on Google is starting to lead me to believe that this libudev.h is only for Ubuntu?  Is this true!?

Answer (score 0):

Its only available for `RedHat 6` not in `RedHat 5`.

```
http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/centos-rhel-i386/libudev-devel-147-2.41.el6.i686.rpm.html
```